# Split a string(looks like list ) into list of values in Hive

Tags: sql, hive

I would like to split an input string which looks like a list into a comma separated strings. Is there a better way to do it. The below SQL doesn't remove the brackets.

Input :

```
"['A','B','C']"
```

Output :

```
'A','B','C'
```

SQL :

```
SELECT Z.str, 
       SPLIT(Z.str,'\W+') str_new
  FROM (
SELECT "['A','B','C']" str ) Z;
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use regexp_replace() to replace braces from the string and then apply split

```
SELECT Z.str, 
       SPLIT(Z.str,'\W+') str_new
  FROM (
SELECT regexp_replace("['A','B','C']", "\\[\\d*\\]", "")  str ) Z
```

Comment: This doesnt produce 'A','B','C'. Square brackets are still coming in the output..

Answer (score 0):

You can use hex values for the special cases like this. \x5b is for "[" and \x5d is for "]". In Hive, you need to escape the \ backslash. Try this, it worked for me.

```
> select regexp_replace("['A','B','C']","[\\x5b\\x5d]", "") str ;
+--------------+--+
|     str      |
+--------------+--+
| 'A','B','C'  |
+--------------+--+
```